# Removing duplicated XAML code by using custom control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

What is a good way to get rid of repeating XAML in different files. Example :

```
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource ViewContentStyle}" Visibility="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToVisibility}}">
                <ctl:NewLabel LabelContent="{x:Static common:LocalResources.UNameLabel}" LabelStyle="{DynamicResource ContentLabelStyle}"
                                    ImageStyle="{DynamicResource ViewContentControlStyle}">
                    <ctl:ETextBox x:Name="UserName"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
                                                LostFocus="Textbox_OnLostFocus"
                                                Text="{Binding Path=UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                    </ctl:ETextBox>
                </ctl:NewLabel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource ViewContentStyle}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedAuthenticationType, Converter={StaticResource AuthToVisibility}}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None">
                    <Label Style="{DynamicResource ContentLabelStyle}" Content="{x:Static common:LocalResources.UPasswordLabel}"/>
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <PwdBox x:Name="Password"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             LostFocus="Textbox_OnLostFocus" PasswordChar="*"
                    </PwdBox>
                </AdornerDecorator>
            </StackPanel>
```

I have 3 files where almost the same code is reused. I think there is a way to get rid of this by using a common custom control. However, I dont see much examples as to how it can be done. Any leads would be great.

Comment: What exactly is different in each piece of Code? Maybe a Style for a ContentPresenter would be sufficent. Additionally i would recommend you to create a User Control instead of a Custom Control. As far as i know, a Custom Control is meant to extend the functionality of an exisitng Control (like a TextBox) and the User Control is to combine some Controls (in your case Stackpanels, Labels, Text and Passworboxes).

Comment: The content and bindings of the custom controls - `ctl:ETextBox` and `PwdBox` are things which are different.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: I guess because someone thought it is not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example due to the lacking information what exactly changes in the markup, more infos see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Add a new [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) to your project and move the common XAML to this one.

You could then create an instance of this `UserControl` (replace "UserControl1" with the actual name of your `UserControl`) in any other view:

```
<!--insert the shared markup here: -->
<local:UserControl1 />
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea as to how to deal with the bindings in the code ? Does that not need any special care ? Referring to the bindings in the control `ETextBox` and `PwdBox`. Also, should the definition of `Textbox_OnLostFocus` go in the code behind of my original XAML or in the code behind of the new `UserControl1` XAML ?

Comment: How to bind depends on how you set the DataContext of the UC, if it's inherited etc. The event handlers should be moved to the code-behind of the UC.